# How to set GMock EXPECT_CALL to invoke two different functions for a mocked function

Tags: c++, googlemock

How to invoke two different functions when a mocked function is called in the tested function in "Test suite"?

Details:
 A mocked function is called twice in a tested function. When it is called the first time, it should invoke one function (a local function in test suite) and when called the second time, it should invoke another function (another local function in test suite).

So, how to set EXPECT_Call with "Invoke" for the above requirement?

Answer (score 8):

You should use `WillOnce`.

Something like this (not tested) :

```
struct A
{
  MOCK_METHOD0( foo, void());
};


class A_Test : public ::testing::Test
{
  A a;

  void bar1(){}
  void bar2(){}
};

TEST_F( A_Test, test_1 )
{
  EXPECT_CALL( a, foo() )
     .WillOnce( Invoke( this, &A_Test::bar1 ) )
     .WillOnce( Invoke( this, &A_Test::bar2 ) );
}
```

Comment: Actually, this answer is accepted but does not work. Result is a large error with "... too many arguments to function". Just copying the code from this answer also does not compile.