# gmock EXPECT_CALL to both return and assign a value to one of the parameters

Tags: googlemock

I am trying to set up a mock with gmock to not only return a value, but to fill in a buffer. The function to be mocked behaves similar to posix read(), as it takes a void* and a size, and will fill in data.

I am trying to put together an action to do that but cannot find a working sample. I find the gmock documentation a little scarce on this.

There is an answer with a call to ::testing::Invoke(), but I cannot get that to compile. Maybe gmock has changed. That answer is 9 years old: [How to set GMock EXPECT_CALL to invoke two different functions for a mocked function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641490/how-to-set-gmock-expect-call-to-invoke-two-different-functions-for-a-mocked-func)

Here's my minimal code showing the call of a mocked 'getdata()'. How can I change the EXPECT_CALL line to fill in the data from the testdata[] array?

Here my code (compiles and makes a failing test, due to missing data):

```cpp
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

// The mock class
class MockDataSrc
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(getdata,int(void *buf,int max));
};

// The Code-Under-Test:
class CUT{
public:
    CUT(MockDataSrc *s){m_s=s;}

    int getandadd()
    {
        unsigned char buf[32];
        unsigned int sum=0;
        int n;
        n=m_s->getdata(buf,sizeof(buf));
        for(int t=0;t<n;t++)sum+=buf[t];
        return (int)sum;
    }
private:
    MockDataSrc *m_s;
};

// The test class:
class Test_CUT : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    Test_CUT(){source=nullptr;}

protected:
    void SetUp() override
    {
        source = new MockDataSrc();
    }

    void TearDown() override
    {
        delete source;
        source=nullptr;
    }

    MockDataSrc *source;

};

// The Test: Call getdata(), verify sum.
TEST_F(Test_CUT, TestGet)
{
    CUT cut(source);
    static const unsigned char testdata[]={13,21,29,37};

    // The expect-call here. How can I supply testdata[] in getdata()?
    EXPECT_CALL(*source,getdata(
            ::testing::NotNull(),::testing::Ge(4)
    )).WillOnce(::testing::Return(4));

    int sum;
    sum = cut.getandadd();
    EXPECT_EQ(sum,100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a late reply, but what you want can be done using a combination of `DoAll`, `SaveArg`, `Invoke`, and `Return`.

Basically, in response to the `getdata` call, you perform the following:

1. Save the `buf` pointer using `SaveArg<0>`.
2. Copy values that you want into the `buf` pointer using a lambda that is called by calling `Invoke`.
3. Return the value 4.

Below is the complete code:

```cpp
#include <cstring>

#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
using ::testing::DoAll;
using ::testing::Invoke;
using ::testing::Return;
using ::testing::SaveArg;

// The mock class
class MockDataSrc {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(int, getdata, (void *, int), ());
};

// The Code-Under-Test:
class CUT {
 public:
  CUT(MockDataSrc *s) { m_s = s; }

  int getandadd() {
    unsigned char buf[32];
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    int n;
    n = m_s->getdata(buf, sizeof(buf));
    for (int t = 0; t < n; t++) {
      sum += buf[t];
    }
    return (int)sum;
  }

 private:
  MockDataSrc *m_s;
};

// The test class:
class Test_CUT : public ::testing::Test {
 public:
  Test_CUT() { source = nullptr; }

 protected:
  void SetUp() override { source = new MockDataSrc(); }

  void TearDown() override {
    delete source;
    source = nullptr;
  }

  MockDataSrc *source;
};

// The Test: Call getdata(), verify sum.
TEST_F(Test_CUT, TestGet) {
  MockDataSrc mock_source;
  CUT cut(&mock_source);
  void *buf;

  static const unsigned char testdata[] = {13, 21, 29, 37};

  // The expect-call here. How can I supply testdata[] in getdata()?
  EXPECT_CALL(mock_source, getdata(::testing::NotNull(), ::testing::Ge(4)))
      .Times(1)
      .WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArg<0>(&buf),
                      Invoke([&buf]() { std::memcpy(buf, testdata, 4); }),
                      Return(4)));

  int sum;
  sum = cut.getandadd();
  EXPECT_EQ(sum, 100);
}
```

Here is a working example: https://godbolt.org/z/zobW6arG5

See [this part](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#SaveArgVerify) in GoogleTest's documentation.